Python Car Class/Methods
your textExecuting the following code, I get the first two methods to print correct results (get_year and #get_cylinders) but the start_engine method does not print correctly. I get the error message: <bound method Car.start_engine of <main.Car object at 0x00000264C7B02510>>
Not sure if I'm not defining the method correctly or not calling it correctly.
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year, cylinders):
        self.__year = year
        self._cylinders = cylinders

    def Car(self, y, c):
        self.__year = y
        self._cylinders = c

    def start_engine():
        return 'Start your engine'

    def set_year(self, y):
        self.__year = y

    def set_cylinders(self, c):
        self.__cylinders = c

    def get_year(self):
        return self.__year

    def get_cylinders(self):
        return self.__cylinders

def main():
    yr = '2020'
    cyl = 4

    myCar = ''
    myCar = Car(yr, cyl)

    myCar.set_year(yr)
    print('The year is: ', myCar.get_year())
    print()

    myCar.set_cylinders(cyl)
    print('The number of cylinders is: ', myCar.get_cylinders())
    print()

    print(myCar.start_engine)

main()

I tried defining the start_engine method (as instructed in the assignment)  to just return the string: 'Start your engine'
I was expecting to call that method and have it print the string.

You have to call the method - myCar.start_engine().

"bound method ..." isn't an error.  It's the representation of the variable you printed, indicating it is a method of an class instance.  As mentioned, you have to call the method to see the results.  Voting to close since this is a common typo.

When I do that, I get the error: TypeError: Car.start_engine() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

You need to accept self as an argument to methods: def start_engine(self): like you did for the others. When you call methods, python will automatically pass the instance to the method as the first argument. If the method doesn't accept that argument, it will result in the error you are seeing.

So, adding () to myCar.start_engine resulted in the error:
TypeError: Car.start_engine() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
I searched SO for a solution to this which is: the '1' argument that was given is the implied 'self' argument. So adding (self) to the start_engine method, as in: def start_engine(self): was the key to solving this problem.
Thanks to all who contributed!

Welcome to SO.
Few issues in your code:

First to answer your question, just put parentheses at the end of myCar.start_engine. Without it, you are printing the method, not executing it. So, changing myCar.start_engine to myCar.start_engine() fixes your problem.
The Car() method is useless. It seems like you have some java background. The __init__ method is the "constructor"
It is anti-pattern to have setters and getters in python.

Hope this helps.

When I add parentheses at the end of myCar.start_engine, I get the error message: TypeError: Car.start_engine() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
